# Why is this activity not starting?

Tags: java, android

I am new to android development. I have an activity which is not even getting to its `onCreate()` function. I am using some 'Log.d's to check flow of control, and no Log.d inside the `onCreate` is getting executed at runtime. What am I doing wrong? The starting part of the class is below:

```
 public class MainActivityap extends Activity
    implements IMediaPlayerServiceClient {
    private StatefulMediaPlayer mMediaPlayer;

    private StreamStation mSelectedStream = new StreamStation("","http://nbc.com/154.mp3");
    private MediaPlayerService mService;
    private boolean mBound;

    private ProgressDialog mProgressDialog;

    /** Called when the activity is first created. */
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        Log.d("msg", "msg0");
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        Log.d("msg", "msg1");
        setContentView(R.layout.main);
        Log.d("msg", "msg2");
        bindToService();
        Log.d("msg", "msg3");
        mProgressDialog = new ProgressDialog(this);
        Log.d("msg", "msg4");
        initializeButtons();
        setupStationPicker();
    }.....
```

Comment: Have you register your Activity in Manifest..?

Comment: I assume no errors?  Please edit your question and include the manifest.

Comment: Please include your AndroidManifest.xml

Comment: How are you calling this activity?

Comment: Ah thanks Pragnani, I hadn't registered it in the manifest, write that as an answer if you want the right answer points.

Comment: @vergilcorleone  Posted answer...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Converting comments as Answer.

Register your activity in the `AndroidManifest.xml`.

```
<activity
        android:name="MainActivityap"
    />
```

Answer (score 1):

Register your activity in `AndroidManifest.xml`

```
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.example.package" 
    ... >

     <activity android:name="MainActivityap" >
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
```

Even if it is *not your main activity*, you have to register it, without the `<intent-filter>`

```
    <activity
        android:name="MainActivityap"
    />
```

Answer (score 1):

Most likely you haven't register your activity in `AndroidManifest.xml` or you did but you haven't specify the `<intent-filters>`. Add this:

```
    <activity
        android:name="<com.yourpackage.yourapp>.MainActivityap"
        android:label="@string/app_name" >
         <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
```

Answer (score 1):

Did you register this Activity as start Activity in AndroidManifest.xml?
just like this:

```
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"    package="com.dutycode.chatchatmain" android:versionCode="1" android:versionName="1.0">
<uses-sdk android:minSdkVersion="9" android:targetSdkVersion="17"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"/>
<application android:allowBackup="true" android:icon="@drawable/chatchat" android:label="@string/app_name" android:theme="@style/AppTheme">
     <activity android:name="com.dutycode.chatchatmain.LoginActivity" android:label="@string/app_name" android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustResize|stateVisible">
          <intent-filter>
                 <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN"/>
                 <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER"/>
          </intent-filter>
     </activity>

</application>
</manifest>
```

Answer (score 1):

may be you have not registered your activity in manifest...

or if registered u may not have set filter in that..

```
        android:name=".MainActivityap"

        android:label="@string/app_name" >

        <intent-filter>

            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />


            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />

        </intent-filter>

    </activity>
```